# Help identifying connector on vinyl shellhead

Tags: audio, connector

I'm working on a DIY project where I'm basically creating/connecting my own vinyl record player arm.

I have one of these shellheads in the picture below. Ideally I wan't to be able to use this, and also use the connector show, without soldering cables directly onto it. **Is this a regular type of connector, which I can buy the female part of? If so, what is it called?** It looks like a short DIN connector, but the pins are perfectly squared, which DIN isn't.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often called an SME tonearm headshell connector 4-pin. 
The mating part is either a replacement SME 3009 or 3012 tonearm or a female SME tonearm 4-pin socket. Here are a few examples of available parts:

http://www.audiosilente.com/spare-parts-for-sme-new-sme-3009-connector-with-gold-plated-pins.html

https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-5pcs-lot-Technics-tonearm-headshell-SME-socket-connector-pure-silver-wire-/123834227569